# Changing MongoDB collection array tree

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a working script which receives and stores the data in MongoDB collection.

Problem: I have a data which is stored in this way (take a look on a screenshot).As you can see I have two branches, first is `Array` and then `0`.

My question is how can I change it, that I will receive a response in MongoDB without this branches(I really don't wan't to click on them to see the response)
Below is a full code example. Any suggestion or solution will be appreciated.

[image]

**FULL CODE**

```
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');
 const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
 const schedule = require('node-schedule');
 var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
 const fetch = require("node-fetch");

 var today = new Date();
 var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
 var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
 var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

 var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', function() {

     fetch('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1h&limit=1')
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(data => {
             const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
                 return { Open: parseFloat(d[1]), High: parseFloat(d[2]), Low: parseFloat(d[3]), Close: parseFloat(d[4]), Volume: parseFloat(d[5]) }
             });
             console.log(btcusdtdata);
             saveToDatabase(btcusdtdata);
         })
 });

 const saveToDatabase = function(BTCdata) {

     const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

     MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
         if (err) throw err;
         const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
         const myobj = { Name: 'BTCUSDT', Array: BTCdata, Date: dateTime };
         dbo.collection('Crypto-Values').insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
             if (error) throw error;
             console.log('1 document inserted');
             db.close();
         });
     });
 };
```

**EDIT1**
So I test the @holydragon comment. Doesn't work for me.

If I do this -  `console.log(btcusdtdata.Array[0]);`

I receive this error - `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: console.log(btcusdtdata.Array[0]);

Comment: @holydragon Thank you for your comment. I receive error in console - `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`